# Django Related model cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, foreign-keys

I have two django/python applications one is running on Django 1.8 and Python 3.4 and the other is running on Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.  These applications share a database and use a python package that houses several of the models that are shared between the two applications in a few different apps.

The application running on 3.4 works fine but the application running on 2.7 throws the ValueError: Relate Model 'model_reference' cannot be resolved.

In this psuedo example the package is core_app the two models are within seperate apps called foobar and barfoo contained in core_app.

**foobar/models.py**

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
   name = TextField()
```

**barfoo/models.py**

```
class Model_B(models.Model):
   model_a = ForeignKey('core_app_foobar.Model_A')
```

Here is the full stack trace.

```
    /home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    125         def create_method(name, method):
    126             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 127                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    128             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
    129             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    326         if self.query.can_filter():
    327             clone = clone.order_by()
--> 328         num = len(clone)
    329         if num == 1:
    330             return clone._result_cache[0]

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __len__(self)
    142 
    143     def __len__(self):
--> 144         self._fetch_all()
    145         return len(self._result_cache)
    146 

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _fetch_all(self)
    963     def _fetch_all(self):
    964         if self._result_cache is None:
--> 965             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    966         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
    967             self._prefetch_related_objects()

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in iterator(self)
    236         # Execute the query. This will also fill compiler.select, klass_info,
    237         # and annotations.
--> 238         results = compiler.execute_sql()
    239         select, klass_info, annotation_col_map = (compiler.select, compiler.klass_info,
    240                                                   compiler.annotation_col_map)

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in execute_sql(self, result_type)
    827             result_type = NO_RESULTS
    828         try:
--> 829             sql, params = self.as_sql()
    830             if not sql:
    831                 raise EmptyResultSet

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in as_sql(self, with_limits, with_col_aliases, subquery)
    376         refcounts_before = self.query.alias_refcount.copy()
    377         try:
--> 378             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
    379             if with_limits and self.query.low_mark == self.query.high_mark:
    380                 return '', ()

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in pre_sql_setup(self)
     46         might not have all the pieces in place at that time.
     47         """
---> 48         self.setup_query()
     49         order_by = self.get_order_by()
     50         extra_select = self.get_extra_select(order_by, self.select)

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in setup_query(self)
     37         if all(self.query.alias_refcount[a] == 0 for a in self.query.tables):
     38             self.query.get_initial_alias()
---> 39         self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
     40         self.col_count = len(self.select)
     41 

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in get_select(self)
    185         if self.query.default_cols:
    186             select_list = []
--> 187             for c in self.get_default_columns():
    188                 select_list.append(select_idx)
    189                 select.append((c, None))

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in get_default_columns(self, start_alias, opts, from_parent)
    522             alias = self.query.join_parent_model(opts, model, start_alias,
    523                                                  seen_models)
--> 524             column = field.get_col(alias)
    525             result.append(column)
    526         return result

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in get_col(self, alias, output_field)
   2015 
   2016     def get_col(self, alias, output_field=None):
-> 2017         return super(ForeignKey, self).get_col(alias, output_field or self.related_field)
   2018 
   2019 

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in related_field(self)
   1895     @property
   1896     def related_field(self):
-> 1897         return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
   1898 
   1899     def get_reverse_path_info(self):

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in foreign_related_fields(self)
   1629     @property
   1630     def foreign_related_fields(self):
-> 1631         return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields)
   1632 
   1633     def get_local_related_value(self, instance):

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in related_fields(self)
   1616     def related_fields(self):
   1617         if not hasattr(self, '_related_fields'):
-> 1618             self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
   1619         return self._related_fields
   1620 

/home/ubuntu/moi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.pyc in resolve_related_fields(self)
   1601             raise ValueError('Foreign Object from and to fields must be the same non-zero length')
   1602         if isinstance(self.rel.to, six.string_types):
-> 1603             raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
   1604         related_fields = []
   1605         for index in range(len(self.from_fields)):

ValueError: Related model 'core_app_foobar.Model_A' cannot be resolved
```

Comment: is a self relationship?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the example code.  Model_B is referencing Model_A

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
class Model_B(models.Model):
   model_a = ForeignKey('foobar.Model_A')
```

don't forget to inherit from django models. (both)

```
from django.db import models
```

> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly
>   specify a model with the full application label. For example, if the
>   Manufacturer model above is defined in another application called
>   production, you’d need to use:

[Doc ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Comment: The model inheritance is not the issue, that was an error in the simplified example.  If that was the issue then the error thrown would have been different.  Also the model is specified with the full application label, and as stated works fine in an application running 1.8/3.4 this issue only comes up in the application running 1.8/2.7.

Comment: then your question was worded wrong, since obviously the first issue where all they see is the name of your app was different from what was imported.

Comment: The focus of this question as I stated in the second sentence is that this package is working fine in an application running on 3.4 and the problem occurs on an application running 2.7.

Comment: When i read this  'but the application 'running on 2.7 throws the ValueError: 
I thought the code was different. but that's okay, you have every right of your downvote.

Comment: I downvoted because that answer doesn't solve this problem, and any users who potentially encounter something like this wont have it solved by these.  The typo's in the psuedocode were my mistake and I've corrected so that they are now syntactically correct.  I appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in one of the following ways-

In **`barfoo/models.py`**-

**1)**

```
from django.db import models

class Model_B(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey('foobar.Model_A')
```

**2)**

```
from django.db import models
from core_app.foobar import models as foobar_models

class Model_B(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(foobar_models.Model_A)
```

Comment: he doesnt need this. look the documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey he doesnt need import the model.